# Accessing subsite of Sharepoint 2013 locally from server keeps asking authentication

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I have a public site `abc.com` and a subsite `abc.com/sites/def` inside Sharepoint Server 2013. 
When I access the subsite from outsite (internet), it works fine.

When I access the subsite locally from the server, it keeps asking authentication.

I don't know why that problem happened. So anybody have experence in this situation?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you fall into loop back issue.Please follow either method to solve it.

**Method 1: Specify host names (Preferred method if NTLM authentication is desired)**

To specify the host names that are mapped to the loopback address and can connect to Web sites on your computer, follow these steps:

- Set the DisableStrictNameChecking registry entry to 1.
- Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
- In Registry Editor, locate and then click the following registry key: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0**
- Right-click MSV1_0, point to New, and then click Multi-String Value.
- Type BackConnectionHostNames, and then press ENTER.
- Right-click BackConnectionHostNames, and then click Modify.
- In the Value data box, type the host name or the host names for the
  sites that are on the local computer, and then click OK.
- Quit Registry Editor, and then restart the IISAdmin service.

**Method 2: Disable the loopback check (less-recommended method)**

The second method is to disable the loopback check by setting the DisableLoopbackCheck registry key.

To set the DisableLoopbackCheck registry key, follow these steps:

- Set the DisableStrictNameChecking registry entry to 1.
- Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
- In Registry Editor, locate and then click the following registry key:
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
- Right-click Lsa, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
- Type DisableLoopbackCheck, and then press ENTER.
- Right-click DisableLoopbackCheck, and then click Modify.
- In the Value data box, type 1, and then click OK.
- Quit Registry Editor, and then restart your computer.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861